# loop through arrays in postgresql table return based on condition and array element position

Tags: arrays, postgresql, loops

I have the following row in a table in a posgresql db:

```
INSERT INTO "public"."position" ("id",
                                 "layout_id",
                                 "dining_table_id",
                                 "x_position",
                                 "y_position",
                                 "translate_x",
                                 "translate_y",
                                 "rotation",
                                 "start_timestamps",
                                 "end_timestamps")
VALUES (683, 32, 683, 1288, 0, E'{0,25}', E'{134,-98}', 0, E'{"2019-03-05 10:24:00","2019-04-05 10:24:00"}', E'{"2019-03-05 21:00:00","2019-04-05 21:00:00"}');
```

I want to make an query, which returns me:

- x_position
- y_position
- rotation

and

- translate_x
- translate_y

But in those columns only if the following condition is met:

If a given timestamp (which comes from the front end and should be part of the condition of the query) is bigger or equal to the start_timestamps and smaller than the end_timestamps array element, which have the same position in the array as the translate_x and translate_y array elements.

So for example if the given timestamp is: 2019-03-05 12:00:00
the array element of the translate_x column with the value 0 (position 0) and the 
array element of the translate_y column with the value 134 (position 0) should be returned, because 2019-03-05 12:00:00 is smaller than end_timestamps columns array element (position 0) and is bigger or equal than the start_timestamps columns array element (position 0).

My question is how can I query the table accordingly? (I hope my table structure makes sense)

My try:

```
const result = await this.db.query(`
SELECT 
       p.x_position,
       p.y_position,
       p.rotation,
FROM POSITION p 
DECLARE 

s int8 := 0;
x int;

BEGIN
FOR x IN s..p.start_timestamps.length LOOP IF p.start_timestamps[x] <= $1
AND p.end_timestamps[x] > $1 THEN RETURN p.translate_x[x], p.translate_y[x] END LOOP;`
[timestamp]);
```

Comment: Please do not post table definitions as screen shots, [edit] your question and add the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the table in question as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) (the same way you did it with the INSERT statement)

Comment: Also show us your query attempt, it is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If If I understood correctly, you can do something like this:

```
select * from (
    select i,id,layout_id,dining_table_id,x_position,y_position,translate_x[i],
           translate_y[i],start_timestamps[i],end_timestamps[i] from (
                          select generate_subscripts(translate_x,1) i,* from position
                  ) a
   ) b where start_timestamps<='2019-03-05 12:00:00'::timestamp 
            and end_timestamps>'2019-03-05 12:00:00'::timestamp
```

It should work, but if you can change the definition of your database, you should create a new table for example:

```
position_periods : (id_position integer ,start_timestamp timestamp,end_timestamp timestamp,translate_x integer,translate_y integer)
```